# Problem with dependencies after upgrading to gradle 7.3.1 in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

After I upgraded to gradle 7.3.1, my project no longer recognizes the classes in my project library that I created. My build.gradle seems to be able to find the library no problem, but my project can't seem to find the classes in my library. I saw that some people recommended deleting the .iml file, but I cant' find any .iml file in my hierarchy.

I already tried invalidating caches and re-starting, and that didn't help. After the upgrade, gradle also recommended that I add the following line to gradle.properties, but I still have a problem w/ or w/o the line added:  "android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true"

Here's my build.gradle for publishing my library to MavenLocal

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.android.library'
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
            android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'        
   implementation'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.5.1'
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
            release(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the release build 
variant.
//                from components.debug

            // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
                groupId = 'com.inmap.MapFragment'
                artifactId = 'debug'
                version = '1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I upgraded from gradle 7.3.1 to 7.4.2 and still have the same problem. My guess is that the syntax in the gradle build files might have changed for picking up a library from Maven Local?

Comment: Another observation. This dependency used to work to pick up my library in my project: "    implementation 'com.inmap.MapFragment:debug:1.0'".  Now, gradle doesn't complain that it can't find the library, but it doesn't show up in the list of declared dependencies when I look in Build -> Edit  Libraries and Dependencies ...

Comment: So, I changed the position of my library dependency in my list. Now it shows up as a declared dependency, but the classes still aren't recognized!!  Arrrgggghhhh!!!

Comment: Another tidbit. My maven local library shows up under declared dependencies for my project, but not under resolved dependencies. Apparently gradle can find the dependency OK because it's not complaining about it. Why wouldn't gradle be able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

So, I still don't know why the link to mavenLocal() didn't work, but I decided to import the library into my project. Now I can at least compile, but the editor still flags the classes as being unrecognized, so I still have some debug to do.

Since I hadn't upgraded in a while, I suppose there were probably a number of things in 7.3.1 that had changed which contributed to the problem. As I figure out additional issues, I will post here.